# loading DLL (ffmpeg) as a new thread

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi, ffmpeg

i would like to improve some existing project (VICE, a c64 emulator).

within this emulator, we can record the emulator screen using the ffmpeg dll's.
the problem here is, these dll's are running in the same thread as the emulator itself. this obviously is unfortunate, the recording should happen in realtime, while the emulator keeps running at 100% speed.

the current code simply loads all dll's using a simple

```
LoadLibrary(name);
```

so my question is: is it possible to load the needed ffmpeg dll's (5 of them) into a new thread?

i searched a lot, but failed to find something that really helped me.
although i found `GetProcAddress`, `CreateThread` and the likes, which at first sight looked promising...

Comment: Are you trying to solve a specific problem? The C64 has a frame buffer of 320x200 pixels, using 2bpp. That's less than 16 KiB per frame. That doesn't appear to be a challenge to encode in real-time while at the same time emulating tens (or even hundreds) of C64s on the same thread. As for the specific question asked: No, you cannot load a DLL into a thread. DLLs are mapped into a process' address space, which is shared by all threads.

Comment: You maybe would be surprised how demanding todays emulators are. Some newer Games or Demos use about 40% of the CPU core on my i5 4th gen system.
This usually also means that ffmpeg is busy. and also, the total core usage should not be above 80% (average), or else the emulator starts to stutter from time to time.
On such systems we need to lower settings, either in the emulator or in the codec settings.

That's why i thought it would make sense to have the recording running in another CPU core. 
But apparently it's not possible without jumping through hoops.

Thanks.

Comment: Emulators aren't demanding in terms of compute power. They are merely burning through CPU cycles to emulate accurate timing. If the goal is to fix performance issues, the first step is to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It would  be possible to do something like the CreateRemoteThread injection, that is either force-cast LoadLibrary to the LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE or implement a very thin wrapper, and place the library name in non-local memory somewhere then use it as the thread argument.

The thing to realize, however, is that libraries and threads really don't have much to do with each other. The important thing to know (and control) is what thread the libraries' functions are being called from. If the program is calling the library functions as part of a particular thread then force-loading it using a different thread isn't going to make any difference, those library calls are still going to be made as part of the calling thread's logic.

Answer (score -1):

`CreateRemoteThread` may meet your requirements.

Just like this:

```
BOOL DllInject(DWORD dwProcessID, LPCTSTR lpDllName)
{
    HANDLE hProcess ;
    //1.open the process
    hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, dwProcessID);
    if (hProcess == NULL) {
        printf("OpenProcess Error!");
        return FALSE;
    }
    //2.alloc memory
    DWORD dwAllocSize = lstrlen(lpDllName) + 1;
    LPVOID lpStrArr = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, NULL, dwAllocSize, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    if (lpStrArr == NULL) {
        printf("VirtualAllocEx Error!");
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
        return FALSE;
    }
    //3.Write Memory
    DWORD dwWriteRet = WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, lpStrArr, (LPVOID)lpDllName, dwAllocSize, NULL);
    if (dwWriteRet == 0) {
        printf("WriteProcessMemory Error!");
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
        return FALSE;
    }
    //4
    HMODULE hModule = GetModuleHandle(L"kernel32.dll");
    if (hModule == NULL) {
        printf("GetModuleHandle Error!");
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
        return FALSE;
    }
    FARPROC  dwProcAddr = GetProcAddress(hModule, "LoadLibraryA");
    if (dwProcAddr == NULL)
    {
        printf("GetProcAddress Error!");
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
        return FALSE;
    }
    //5.CreateRemoteThread
    HANDLE hThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)dwProcAddr, lpStrArr, 0, NULL);
    if (hThread == NULL)
    {
        printf("CreateRemoteThread Error! :%d\n",GetLastError());
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
        return FALSE;
    }
    //6.CloseHandle
    CloseHandle(hProcess);
    return TRUE;
}
```

Then call it in `main()`

```
DllInject(pId//process id, L"xxx.dll"//your dlls need to be injected);
```

However, the behavior of CreateRemoteThread may be considered unsafe by the system.

Comment: The OP has source code access. There's no reason to inject a thread into a foreign process. And if you do, you'll want to make sure that you're doing it right. `LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE` and `LoadLibraryA` have different function signatures, so this hack works by coincidence only.